# Freemarker and Spring Validation Error Message Doesn't show up error messages

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, freemarker

Hi I am working on spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and added spring-webmvc (4.3.13.RELEASE) dependency.

When I hit the submit button with some form data, it goes to server and checks if there're some errors, and prints it on console, and return back to form input page. but there is no error messages printed.

I submit the form with ModelAttribute object and the object is defined like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MEMBER", uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"USER_SEQ"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"USER_EMAIL"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"NICKNAME"})
})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
public class Member implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_SEQ", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long userSeq; 

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @Column(name="USER_EMAIL", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
    private String userEmail;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @Column(name="USER_PW", nullable=false, length=255)
    private String userPw;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=10)
    @NonNull
    @Column(name="NICKNAME", unique=true, nullable=false, length=20)
    private String nickname;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="member", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private MemberSecurity security;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member [userSeq=" + userSeq + ", userEmail=" + userEmail + ", userPw=" + userPw + ", nickname="
                + nickname + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Member other = (Member) obj;
        if (userSeq == null) {
            if (other.userSeq != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userSeq.equals(other.userSeq))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((userSeq == null) ? 0 : userSeq.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

In Controller which the submit goes through, I coded like below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/join", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String join(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("join") Member member, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirect){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            viewNameChooser.joinForm(model);
            System.err.println("ERROR COUNT: " + bindingResult.getErrorCount());
            System.err.println("ERROR FIELD: " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getField());
            System.err.println("ERROR CODE: " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getCode());

            return go();
        }

        redirect.addFlashAttribute("joinSuccess", String.valueOf(memberService.save(member)) );

        return "redirect:/member/login-form";
    }
```

and the console output is :

```
ERROR COUNT: 1
ERROR FIELD: nickname
ERROR CODE: Size
```

Now I registered my custom error messages in classpath:META-INF/messages.properties:

```
Email.member.userEmail=It is not email type text.
NotNull.member.userEmail=Please, type your email id.
NotNull.member.userPw=Please, type your password.
NotNull.member.nickname=Please, type your nickname.
Size.member.nickname=The length of nickname must be greater than or equal 2 and less than or equal 10.
```

So far so good, but in my freemarker template, there is no error message displayed. I have coded like below:

```
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"] />

<form id="join-form" action="<@spring.url '/member/join' />" method="post" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
    <@spring.bind "join" />

    <#-- skipped -->

    <@form.errors "*" />

    <#-- skipped -->
</form>
```

> <@form.errors "*" />

should contain error messages but it's not. Where am I missing? Help me please.

**EDIT: I modified my controller method.**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/join", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView join(@Valid @ModelAttribute("join") Member member, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirect){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            //viewNameChooser.joinForm(bindingResult);
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("template", bindingResult.getModel());
            modelAndView.addObject("viewName", "joinForm");;
            System.err.println("ERROR COUNT: " + bindingResult.getErrorCount());
            System.err.println("ERROR FIELD: " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getField());
            System.err.println("ERROR CODE: " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getCode());

            return modelAndView;
        }

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/member/login-form");
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("joinSuccess", String.valueOf(memberService.save(member)) );

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Now I am using ModelAndView.

Comment: What does your `go()` method do. Looks like it returns something..

Comment: go() returns string "template", and the template means /META-INF/templates/template.ftl.

Comment: Remove the `Model` attribute from your method signature.

Comment: After removing ModelAttribute annotation, when I hit submit, the errors printed: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'join' available as request attribute

Comment: Read, again read... I stated `Model` attribute from your method signature NOT `@ModelAttribute`...

Comment: I need model....  viewNameChooser.joinForm(model); line uses model, nevertheless, do I need to remove it?

Comment: The `BindingResult` is the `Model`... However as you now have 2 models the wrong one is going to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the clue!, but I need to call model.addAttribute("viewName", "joinForm"); how do I call this line? BindingResult doesn't have a method like that.

Comment: Modified viewName resolving code to bindingResult.getModel().put("viewName", "joinForm");, now I have another error in freemarker page:   ------->             when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: #macro url relativeUrl extra... [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "url" at line 89, column 1] - Reached through: @spring.url "/css/${viewName}.css"

Comment: That won't work, the `getModel` recreates the model and adding stuff to it won't work.

Comment: How about using HttpServletRequest in controller method parameter? could request.setAttribute("viewName", "joinForm"); work?

Comment: That is what eventually happens. But you might be better of returning a `ModelAndView`.

Comment: **ModelAndView.setViewName("template");** is okay, but I have to add line **modelAndView.addObject("viewName", "joinForm");** but it is not the same model with BindingResult as you said. how do I resolve it...

Comment: `ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("template", bindingResult.getModel());` then `mav.addObject("viewName", "joinForm")`;

Comment: still doesn't work. in console view, it says there is a validation errror, but in freemarker view, nothing printed. I editted my post with modified controller method.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well I am sorry to say but I should say, I think it is the same **Model** from the parameter and BindingResult.getModel(). I mean spring shares model map. and deliver into different form with Model parameter or model property in BindingResult, and **<@spring.showErrors "<br/>" />** code prints error message regardless different models. Now I have to search more about <@form.errors/> tag. thank you.